# Loading new Views

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, uiview

Ok so I'm sure I'm missing this somewhere but I think I need someone else to bounce this off as I've been going around in circles on this for some time.

My situation is quite straight forward really.

I've got two files 
TapView.m
TapView.h

which are loaded when the AppController.m calls the showTapView method.

```
    -(void) showTapView {
[tapViewController resetAllStates:self];
[navigationController pushViewController animated:YES];
[tapViewController prepareTapView];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:tapViewController];
}
```

Now this all works swell and loads TapView in happily enough. It's not *really* an issue, but I don't like building interfaces progmatically, what I'd love to be able to do is to change this method so that instead of loading a progmatically created view it calls on a XIB based view, let's call it ***LazyView*** for the sake of arguments.

Now if it's a big thing to do this I'm happy as is and can leave it progmatically inclined, it's just that having it working through Interface Builder will help me significantly in the future as I expand the application further :)

---

If anyone's wondering by the way, I've built the app using some samples from open source projects, the app doesn't bear much resemblance these days but it was from Remotepad - many thanks to the guys for the release of the source, it helped me get my head around Bonjour no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `initWithNibName` method to load a view controller from a Nib.

```
UIViewController* controller = [[LazyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LazyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: Hm, I get two red errors with this - let me explain what I did - created new UIViewController subclass, inserted the code above  in place of the code I gave. First error reads 'LazyViewcontroller undeclared (first use in this function) on the first line. The second reads "Accessing unknown 'navigationController' getter method' on the secondline.

Comment: Just to update, I adjusted my AppController.h appropriately (doh!) and now the first line just warns that LazyViewController is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist. Second line retains it's error.

Comment: When you make a nib file, you can set the class name. Usually this would be some custom class that extends UIViewController. If you want to test that the nib is loading, you can use `UIViewController` (which exists) instead if `LazyViewController` (which you would have to create).

Comment: True that could well work for what I need. My 'lazy view' was just for sake of argument ;-) I've just modified to UIViewController and it seems to work, at least at a cursory glance. I'll have to experiment later when I'm done for the day and see if it'll allow me to keep the functionality I got in my programmed intverface. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Right so I've spent some time trying this out. Adding the new UIViewController as suggested works but there's a catch (when isn't there?) What I'm actually replacing is the TapView (LazyView was a bad example) and when I replace it with this new ViewController the whole app sort of breaks. Essentially it's very heavily coded throughout to rely on tapViewController and to check back and what have you (it's a Networking app so it's like spaghetti junction in there) is there a way I can add a new .xib to my TapView.m Tapview.h and have them refer to it for the interface layout rather than code?

Comment: You can make it so that the .xib is built with any view controller you want, in interface builder just change `UIViewController` to `tapViewController`, or `YourCustomViewController`. You would then alloc your view controller like in my answer above. At that point you can add your methods, implement default methods like `viewDidLoad`, do things with delegates, interact with the UI, etc. Anything you would normally do in code.

Comment: Ok so I've got this wired in right now I think, however I'm still seeing a warning on the first line reading that TapViewController may not respond to '-alloc' , normally i'd not fret too much but when the app calls for the view to load it crashes out so I'm thinking this is probably key. Going to search around now but if you have any great thoughts I'll owe you  pack of jelly babies :) -  Think I got it.

Comment: Interface Builder can be a lot to wrap your head around. Its pretty cool once you do though. Does your TapViewController extend UIViewController? It should inherit alloc from there.